# Combing conditional class binding with existing class

Tags: ember.js

I am noticing an issue with conditional attribute bindings when trying to combine them with a regular class on the same element. Here is the handlebars markup I am trying:

```
<a href="#" class="button" {{bindAttr class="isDirty:dirty:clean"}} {{action save}}>Save</a>
```

What I expect to be generated is:

```
<a href="#" class="button clean" data-bindattr-3="3" data-ember-action="4">Save</a>
```

But what is actually generated is:

```
<a href="#" class="button" data-bindattr-3="3" data-ember-action="4">Save</a>
```

When I modify the model, it correctly generates the dirty class:

```
<a href="#" class="button dirty" data-bindattr-3="3" data-ember-action="4">Save</a>
```

If I try move the class after the binding, it will generate the conditional class rather than the declared one:

```
<a href="#" {{bindAttr class="isDirty:dirty:clean"}} class="button" {{action save}}>Save</a>
```

Generates the conditional but not button class:

```
<a href="#" class="clean" data-bindattr-3="3" data-ember-action="4">Save</a>
```

What I want is to have it generate both the combined declared class and the conditional class using just Handlebars (without having to create a view). Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the [template guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-class-names/#toc_static-classes) it describes a way to combine static and bound classes for one item:

> If you need an element to have a combination of static and bound classes, you should include the static class in the list of bound properties, prefixed by a colon.

In your case you would do something like this:

```
<a href="#" {{bindAttr class=":button isDirty:dirty:clean"}} {{action save}}>Save</a>
```

Here is a working example http://jsbin.com/ixupad/82/edit

Comment: Thank you, not sure how I missed that.

Comment: `bindAttr` is aliased to `bind-attr` and soft-deprecated since 
[Ember 1.0 RC8](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/08/29/ember-1-0-rc8.html#toc_other-improvements).

Answer (score 5):

As of Ember 1.11 you may use [inline-if-syntax](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/templates/conditionals/#toc_inline-if-syntax)

```
<a href="#" class="button {{if isDirty 'dirty' 'clean'}}" {{action save}}>
  Save
</a>
```